# how to make a js code not working on the first twoo times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function named `onAddressChange()` which executes when a DOM ready 2 times. I don't want that because a success message that I have inserted on it should appear only when the function is triggered after a customer clicks on the change.

Is there any way to avoid entering this function after the DOM was initialized or something like that? I do not want the success message to appear the first time the page loads.

```js
define([
  'jquery',
  'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
  'mage/translate'
], function($, selectBillingAddress, $t) {
  'use strict';

  return function(Component) {
    return Component.extend({
      onAddressChange: function(address) {
        this._super();
        
        // showing succes message
        let messageSucces = $t('Your billing address has been updated');
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.checkout-billing-address .billing-address-details').after('<div class="billing-address-msg">' + messageSucces + '</div>');
        }, 1000)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

> in other expression, how to make this code not working on the first twoo times for example

Comment: You say that you want function to be called when customer clicks something right? Can't you assign this to onClick event?

Comment: the function already on the change event  <select class="select" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
        options: addressOptions,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        value: selectedAddress,
        event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};

Comment: I am not good at Jquery but I found something you may use. If your function is connected to $(document).ready. You should remove it from there and just define call the function when you need.(if this is not the case) Maybe you can also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802993/prevent-executing-js-function-on-page-load